# Why doesn't the `default` value work in mongoose schema when nothing was entered?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database

This is my Schema and the image `default` value doesn't seem to work when I leave the HTML input field empty before submitting a "blog" post.

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: {
        type: String,
        default: "some image url"
    },
    body: String,
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

this is the input that is going into the database.

```
{ __v: 0,
  title: '',
  body: '',
  _id: 583af591c460fca539b8f787,
  created: 2016-11-27T15:02:41.613Z,
  image: '' }
```

I don't understand what the problem is since the `image` doesnt have any value and it isn't setting the default value.

Comment: If you leave the HTML field empty, your browser will still send the empty string to the server. Because you're then defining data in your model instance (in this case, empty string), Mongoose won't use the default.

Comment: @slugonamission So it is basically sending an empty string and since it is technically still a string, Mongoose won't use the default? Do you know a way of getting around this?

Comment: Your application logic can implement the "default" behaviour for you (i.e. if `""` posted, replace with either `undefined` to make Mongoose fill in the default, or fill in the default manually). There's no magic bullet to make Mongoose do it all for you

Comment: @slugonamission Thanks for helping. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I had the same issue, so thanks for this.  I also at first expected Mongoose to treat the falsy empty string as a non-value.  Would be nice to at least have a setting to control this, defaultOnFalsy or something...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding an if statement as follows:

```
if(image === '') {
  image = undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clean out empty strings and anything else you think you don't want. Maybe try this lodash function before passing the object to mongo.

`_.pickBy(updateObject, v => v !== null && v !== undefined && v !== ""); // removes all null, undefined and empty string values`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar difficulty and I opted for using a variable with a default value. It will be included when you are attempting to do the POST request.

```
var image = req.body.image || "some default value";
```

That assuming the user hasn't input anything, which makes its value **null** by default when the data is send to the backend.